# docker nodejs container cant connect mysql container

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, connection

I'm running Docker server in Digital Ocean. There I have two containers Nodejs and Mysql. Mysql container has open port to 3306.

When trying to access mysql via nodejs by Docker Server ip + port. I get Error: connect ETIMEDOUT.

When I run same nodejs docker setup in my local computer it works fine. Is there something i'm missing?

Here is nodejs docker-composer.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
    test-web-install:
        image: example-nodejs:latest
        working_dir: /home/app
        volumes:
        - ./:/home/app
        command: sh -c 'nodemon'
        environment:
        - NODE_ENV=development
        - DB_HOST=192.168.11.207 #or public ip in internet
        - DB_PORT=3036
        - DB_PASSWORD=root
        - DB_USER=root
        - DB_DATABASE=root
        ports:
        - "3000:3000"
```

Here is docker-composer.yml for mysql

```
mysql:
    container_name: flask_mysql
    restart: always
    image: mysql:5.6
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root' # TODO: Change this
        MYSQL_USER: 'root'
        MYSQL_PASS: 'root'
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'root'
    volumes:
    - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
    - "3036:3306"
    restart: always
```

Comment: Do you try to reach mysql container via `localhost:3306` on your local computer ? Please provide more information - docker files/ docker-compose / outputs. So far my suggestion is to use docker-compose and to connect to mysql container from within bridge network using docker-compose dns (i.e. `mysql:3306`) if your setup can allow that the db will be avialable only to your node.js server.

Comment: I would like to access to DB also by Mac client like Sequal Pro. I added those setups files. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Did you tried connect6ing via domain name? First need to check if is there anything listens and if there no firewall: `sudo netstat -tulpen` , `sudo ufw status verbose`. If not this article probably could help : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/docker-explained-how-to-containerize-and-use-nginx-as-a-proxy

Comment: Looks like it's something to do with docker network settings. Some how the container ip is 128.0.0.1 insteed host ip. Is it possible to use host ip?

Comment: I also added those to same network in docker. Even Curl operation dosen't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll modify answer as we advance - Following your comments, while I can not access to your env, lets try to solve this incrementally:

1. Let's make the db visible to the node.js server
2. See how it works and then probably dive into env networking configuration.

There 2 ways to solve 1st and may be 2nd problem as i see without being able to touch your env:

1st one will ensure that the server sees the database, but if you can not connect to the db from outside seems there firewall/droplet networking configuration issue, and you can try 2nd way (wont likely to change, but it's good to try). This assumes you use same docker compose and same bridge cusom network:

```
version: '2'
services:
    test-web-install:
        image: example-nodejs:latest
        working_dir: /home/app
        volumes:
        - ./:/home/app
        command: sh -c 'nodemon'
        environment:
        - NODE_ENV=development
        - DB_HOST= mysql 
        - DB_PORT=3036
        - DB_PASSWORD=root
        - DB_USER=root
        - DB_DATABASE=root
        ports:
        - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      inner:
        alias: server
  mysql:
    container_name: flask_mysql
    restart: always
    image: mysql:5.6
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root' # TODO: Change this
        MYSQL_USER: 'root'
        MYSQL_PASS: 'root'
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'root'
    volumes:
    - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
    - "<externalEnvIp>:3036:3306"
    restart: always
    networks:
      inner:
        alias: mysql
networks:
  inner:
      driver: bridge
      driver_opts:
        com.docker.network.enable_ipv6: "true"
        com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade: "true"
      ipam:
        driver: default
        config:
        - subnet: 172.16.100.0/24
          gateway: 172.16.100.1
```

Option 2 :

```
version: '2'
services:
    test-web-install:
        image: example-nodejs:latest
        working_dir: /home/app
        volumes:
        - ./:/home/app
        command: sh -c 'nodemon'
        environment:
        - NODE_ENV=development
        - DB_HOST= mysql 
        - DB_PORT=3036
        - DB_PASSWORD=root
        - DB_USER=root
        - DB_DATABASE=root
        ports:
        - "3000:3000"
        network_mode: "host"
  mysql:
    container_name: flask_mysql
    restart: always
    image: mysql:5.6
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root' # TODO: Change this
        MYSQL_USER: 'root'
        MYSQL_PASS: 'root'
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'root'
    volumes:
    - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
    - "3036:3306"
    restart: always
    network_mode: "host"
```

More precise  solution (to find the roots of the problem) would involve into deep digging into your env network configuration, docker networking settings etc., but those solutions may help and fix your problem for now.

Pleasse after you try please output the results.

Comment: Solution 1 is the best solution for our case! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The docker networking doesn't allow you to go from inside a container back out to the host IP to connect to a port exposed by another container. I haven't dug into this enough to see if that's due to the iptables rules or perhaps something inside of docker-proxy. Either way, it's never been worth investigating since container-to-container networking is a built in feature of docker.

To use docker's networking, the containers need to be on the same docker network, and you reference them by their container name in DNS. With docker-compose, normally you can use the service name in place of the container name (e.g. test-web-install and mysql from your examples) since compose creates an alias for these. However, since you've overridden the container name for mysql, use your flask_mysql container name instead.

In your scenario, since you've split up the startup with two separate docker-compose.yml files, you'll be on separate networks created by compose. You have two options to resolve this:

1. Merge the two into a single docker-compose.yml ([BlackStork gave an example of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42891590/596285)).
2. Use an externally defined network that you create in advance.

To do the latter, first create your network:

```
docker network create dbnet
```

Then update your docker-compose.yml for the app to look like:

```
version: '2'
networks:
    dbnet:
        external: true

services:
    test-web-install:
        image: example-nodejs:latest
        working_dir: /home/app
        volumes:
        - ./:/home/app
        command: sh -c 'nodemon'
        environment:
        - NODE_ENV=development
        - DB_HOST=flask_mysql
        - DB_PORT=3036
        - DB_PASSWORD=root
        - DB_USER=root
        - DB_DATABASE=root
        ports:
        - "3000:3000"
        networks:
        - dbnet
```

And the docker-compose.yml for mysql:

```
version: '2'

networks:
  dbnet:
    external: true

services:

  mysql:
    container_name: flask_mysql
    restart: always
    image: mysql:5.6
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root' # TODO: Change this
        MYSQL_USER: 'root'
        MYSQL_PASS: 'root'
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'root'
    volumes:
    - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
    - "3036:3306"
    restart: always
    networks:
    - dbnet
```